# kdb - Loading csv and assigning table

Tags: kdb

I have a `testdata` file on my home directory (csv) following the [FAQ](http://code.kx.com/q/cookbook/faq/) . For each of the below I get an ERROR

```
\l /absolute/path/to/testdata
\l testdata
data: get `:/absolute/path/to/testdata
data: get `:testdata
```

What's wrong with them?

But this works then `table: ("ISI"; enlist ",") 0:`testdata``. How do I use this command with an absolute path?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use `0:` to read your csv:

```
("ISI"; enlist ",") 0: `:/absolute/path/to/testdata
```

`\l` loads q code:

```
\l u.q
```

`get` reads a kdb+ data file.

Comment: Code only answers are not considered good answers, please add a few lines explaining how this fixes the issue